# Add tiles.xml from another maven modules

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tiles2

I have 3 maven modules. In one module MAIN - I have dependency from 2 another (MODULE1 and MODULE2). All modules based on spring mvc. 
So, in all modules I use tiles as template constructor. 
In MAIN module in mvc-dipatcher-servlet.xml i try to configurate it

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass">
        <value>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/module-one-tiles.xml</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/module-main-tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But it gives me an error, that it cannot find `module-one-tiles.xml` file. I also tried to use `classpath*`, the same result. Is it possible to add `tiles.xml` files from another maven modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your module jar contains `/WEB-INF/module-one-tiles.xml` at this location and your module jar is in classpath of your MAIN module then

```
<value>classpath:/WEB-INF/module-one-tiles.xml</value>
```

would work

Comment: No, It doesn't work. java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/ub-blog-tiles.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist. And what does it mean "your module jar is in classpath of your MAIN module then"? In my main module.pom I have        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.springapp</groupId>
            <artifactId>moduleone</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>    and in moduleone pom <groupId>com.springapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>moduleone</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

Comment: post structure of your module jar which contains this xml file

Comment: Path to xml is: src -- main -- webapp -- WEB-INF -- module-one-tiles.xml

Comment: in your jar please, and edit your question to include it

Comment: Oh, i opened it. It doesn't provide any resourses... Can you help me, what I need to add to moduleone pom.xml to add resourses to jar?

Comment: please post your jar structure that contains this xml files in your question

Comment: It only hase one controller.java file. Thats all

Comment: I think I understand. I changed my pom file(add resourses import) and it start working. Now I need to set normal directory in module jar, I think I will understand it) thank you very much